# Directory iteration using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a diirectory containing textfiles,I normaly use  DirectoryIterator class avaialble in php to iterate the directory and get filenames .I've got trouble trying it with CI. I'm completely new to CI ,so please bear with me :).

**I've got something like this in my default controller named myblog**   (i wrote the function just after the index function).

```
<?php

    public function diriterate()
    {
        $this->load->helper('directory');

        $mapi=directory_map('./myfolder/');

        $this->load->view('index.php',$mapi);       
    } 

?>
```

**and i'm trying something like this in my view**

```
<?php
    foreach($mapi as $key)
    {   
        echo $key;  
    }
?>
```

Am i doing it plain wrong here ? .

**(1)** If my understanding is correct i can run it like mysitename/class/function (**in my case localhost/myblog/diriterate**) **(2)** My directory is inside the rootfolder (rootfolder/myfolder) so there is no need of baseurl or something ?.

Should i do this simply in the view using DirectoryIterator class or just create another controller for iteration,I'm really confused , any help is welcome .Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably start using CI after reading about MVC pattern for web apps. This could help you structure your application better. Also refer CI user guide for reference with code igniter configurations and available libraries and classes.

Comment: appart from proper **MVC** structure, when passing data to a **view** you need to send it as an array('mapi' => $mapi)

Comment: thanks guys,seems I need to improve my grasp of mvc a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the MVC convention.

**Model** models/folder_model.php

```
class Folder_model extends CI_Model {
    function iterate() {
        $this->load->helper('directory');
        $map = directory_map('./myfolder', 1);
        return $map;
    }
}
```

For the directory map, it'll look in the root directory of your application, meaning path that includes `index.php`. Note that `1` will cause it to be non-recursive and only on that top-level path.

**Controller** controllers/folder.php

```
class Folder extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {
        $this->load->model('folder_model');
        $map = $this->folder_model->iterate();

        $this->load->view('folder', array('map' => $map));
    }
}
```

**View** views/folder.php

```
<? foreach ($map as $item): ?>
    <?= $item ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This then would be viewable at `http://localhost/index.php/folder`.

Comment: Thank you very much,i thought i could accomplish this without using a model,is there any possibility of that ?.

Comment: You should always use the MVC convention. If your codebase gets bigger and you shove everything into the controllers, you're defeating the purpose of MVC and your code will really be jumbled. All in all, it'll help you in the end.